# SQL SERVER QUERY EXEC sp_helptext

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to use EXEC sp_helptext for each stored procedure in the database.

So I would like to use EXEC sp_stored_procedures and retrieve the PROCEDURE_NAME from it to execute : EXEC sp_helptext *PROCEDURE_NAME* in loop.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call sp_helptext per proc, you can get them all in a single query:

```
select sm.definition
from sys.sql_modules sm 
inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = sm.object_id
where o.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'PRINT ''SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ' + case uses_quoted_identifier when 1 then 'ON''' else 'OFF' + '''' end  + char(13) + char(10)
+ 'PRINT ''GO ''' + char(13) + char(10)
+ 'PRINT ''SET ANSI_NULLS ' + case uses_ansi_nulls when 1 then 'ON''' else 'OFF' + '''' end + char(13) + char(10) 
+ 'PRINT ''GO ''' + char(13) + char(10)
+ 'GO'  
+ char(13) + char(10) + 'sp_helptext ' + o.name + char(13) + char(10) + 'GO' + char(13) + char(10)
+ 'PRINT ''GO ''' + char(13) + char(10)

FROM          sys.all_sql_modules AS m
JOIN          sys.all_objects AS o 
ON                   m.Object_ID = o.Object_ID
JOIN          sys.schemas AS s 
ON                   o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE         o.is_ms_shipped=0
------------------------------------------------------
-- custom filters below
------------------------------------------------------

and o.type = 'SP'
```

So all of that other stuff in the beginning is because sp_helptext doesn't also have whether or not ansi nulls or quoted identifiers were set to anything in particular. This script will create a script that can hopefully be run for your needs.